# Which php/js functions does this website probably user in order to autorefresh itself?

Tags: javascript, php

This webpage http://cml.kg/test.php refreshes 10som.kg.
1. How does test.php embed 10som.kg even though 10som.kg 
uses x-frame-options : SAMEORIGIN?
Doesn't it mean that you can't embed it on any other website? How did test.php bypass this restriction?
2. Test.php doesn't only refresh the embedded page, but also clicks the button on it until the URL changes. How?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to check the source code of the website in question by yourself?

Comment: yes, but I don't see any differences between the original and the embedded one. There's no way I can see php code :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question 1. 10som.kg probably has CORS enabled in the server.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

If that's true, this allows other domains to make ajax request to it.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about CORS.